# How to display ul list in two columns in one row?

Tags: html, css

I have the list as below:

```
<div class="ListStyle">
   <ul>
      <li>List1
         <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
            <li>ChildList2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>List2
           <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
           </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div
```

i wanna display in this format: (Parent li in one raw, two columns, then child li in one column multi raws)

List1                           List2

       ChildList1               ChildList1

       ChildList2

Comment: You may still want to follow a "strict" doctype instead of transitional. If you add strict, IE will behave properly.

Comment: I see, but i am working on a 10 years old page. I don't have any guts to add this strict. I can only try to make it works as is:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.ListStyle ul li {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.ListStyle ul li ul li {
 float: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ListStyle">
   <ul>
      <li>List1
         <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
            <li>ChildList2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>List2
           <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
           </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iqovo).

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial Here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

```
.yourElement ul li { display: inline; }

.yourElement ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following is what you are looking for:

```
.ListStyle ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.ListStyle ul li ul li {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css (still experimental). In this [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts) they show how to do it.

To be short, this should be in your css:

```
ul
{
columns: 2 12em; /* two columns, each 12em width */
column-gap: 1em; /* spacing between columns */
column-rule: 1px dashed silver; /* border between columns */
-moz-columns: 2 12em; /* for Gecko */
-moz-column-gap: 1em;
-moz-column-rule: 1px dashed silver;
-webkit-columns: 2 12em; /* for WebKit */
-webkit-column-gap: 1em;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px dashed silver;
}
```

This [post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t604914-is-it-possible-to-split-a-ul-list-into-two-columns.html) in another forum may be useful. Also this [site](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) shows how to do it in IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would just float these lists next to one another?

```
<div id="left-float">
  <ul>
    <li>List1</li>
    <li><ul>
          <li>ChildList1</li>
          <li>ChildList2</li>
        <ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="right-float">
  <ul>
    <li>List2</li>
    <li><ul>
          <li>ChildList1</li>
        <ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then you would have your css that reads like this (if you were trying to fit these lists into a space 800px wide, for instance):

```
#left-float
{
  float:left;
  width:400px;
}

#right-float
{
  float:right;
  width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<style type="text/css">
div.ListStyle>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.ListStyle>ul>li {
    display:inline;
}

div.ListStyle>ul>li>div {
    float: left;
}
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="ListStyle">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
        List1
        <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
            <li>ChildList2</li>
         </ul> 
         </div>
      </li>
      <li><div>
        List2
           <ul> 
            <li>ChildList1</li>
           </ul> 
           </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: There I fixed it. Now it will